# Geometry and Geography data types in mysql

Tags: mysql, geometry, spatial, sqldatatypes

Sql sever have Spatial Data Types geometry and geography. There is geometry type is available in mysql, but I didn't find mysql geography in mysql.

I what to check intersection of location (Latitude,Longitude) with polygon geofence. I have done this in java, but that solution is too slow. Hence in sql server database I use geography datatype to store polygon geofence points data. And that give me faster result.

In mysql I din't find geograqphy data type. Latitude and longitude represent the angles.

so what if I use geometry datatype to store polygon geofece 
points(latitude,longitude) in mysql?

it will give me same result as geography?

Comment: Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html

Comment: Was it really too difficult to enter `Geometry and Geography data types in mysql` into Google rather than starting a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @SathishD, I found description about geometry object in above document link, and not about Geography. I what to store location objects with Latitude and Longitude

Comment: @AMY:- To store Latitude and Longitude, you can use DECIMAL datatype in MYSQL. To be specific, use DECIMAL(10, 8) for Latitudes as it range from -90 to +90 (degrees), and for longitude you can use DECIMAL(11, 8) as its range is from -180 to +180 (degrees).

Comment: @RahulTripathi, I want to store polygon geofence object in column same as I did in sql server.

Comment: @AMY:- Then you can go with the datatypes as mentioned in the answer. Also latitude and longitude are usually stored in DECIMAL just because of accuracy.

Comment: @RahulTripathi, thanks for reply, but I have one doubt. Latitude and Longitude represent the angels, so is it ok to use latlang values in geometry? Geometry polygon is same as Geography?

Comment: @AMY:- Yes you can proceed with that.

Comment: @RahulTripathi, ok Rahul I will go with it. I want to check polygon geofence intersection with one goelocation. I have done this in java but that solution is too slow.

Comment: @AMY:- I am not sure if I understand it correctly  but you can find this helpful: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/

Comment: @Pekka웃, I think I am not succeed to describe my problem correctly.

Comment: There is a distinction between `geometry` and `geography` types, e.g. in PostGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-postgis-geography-and-geometry-types `geography` has certain advantages, including the use of geodetic rather than planar calculations, and better handling of the antimerdian (±180° longitude).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL has data types that correspond to OpenGIS classes. Some of these types hold single geometry values:

```
GEOMETRY

POINT

LINESTRING

POLYGON
```

`GEOMETRY` can store geometry values of any type. The other single-value types `(POINT, LINESTRING, and POLYGON)` restrict their values to a particular geometry type.

The other data types hold collections of values:

```
MULTIPOINT

MULTILINESTRING

MULTIPOLYGON

GEOMETRYCOLLECTION
```

`GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` can store a collection of objects of any type.

The other collection types `(MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, and GEOMETRYCOLLECTION)` restrict collection members to those having a particular geometry type.

Also you can refer this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-data.html

Comment: Thanks! Which one should I use for a geo location aware app? GEOMETRY or POINT?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its there in MYSQL. You can look for [11.5.1 Spatial Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html)

> MySQL has data types that correspond to OpenGIS classes. Some of these
>   types hold single geometry values:
>
> - GEOMETRY
> - POINT
> - LINESTRING
> - POLYGON
>
> **GEOMETRY can store geometry values of any type.** The other single-value
>   types (POINT, LINESTRING, and POLYGON) restrict their values to a
>   particular geometry type.

**EDIT:**

To store Latitude and Longitude, you can use DECIMAL datatype in MYSQL. To be specific, use `DECIMAL(10, 8)` for Latitudes as it range from -90 to +90 (degree), and for longitude you can use `DECIMAL(11, 8)` as its range is from -180 to +180 (degree).

Comment: But, if I use DECIMAL I don't have available all the spatial functions, right? Shouldn't I use GEOGRAPHY or POINT? Thanks.